# List all functions declared in header but missing in the source file?

Tags: c, header-files, static-analysis

## Question

Are there some linters/statical analyzers that warn/error on functions, that are declared in the header file but not implemented in the corresponding source file?

Lets say we have the following header (guard omitted):

```
/* example.h */
int doSomething(int i);
double doSomethingElse(double d);
```

And the following source:

```
/* example.c */
#require "example.h"

int doSomething(int i) {
  return i + 1;
}
```

So is there some tool, that can tell me that `doSomethingElse()` is missing in `example.c`?

## Why asking?

In an exercise we got some headerfiles with a fully fletched interface, and partially prepared sourcefiles, with some functions beeing fully provided, some functions beeing partially provided, and some missing.

For actually running and compiling this programm it was enough to complete the partially provided functions, but still there is some discrepancy between the defined interface in the header and the now provided functions in the source file.

I could go through all header/source pairs by hand and implement the missing funtions, but it would be nice to have some autogenerated todolist.

Comment: unless you want to check many functions, most integrated development environments (IDEs) and also some coding text editors have tools or plugins to go to a definition of a function from the declaration. You could use that and see if the editor manages to find the definition.

Comment: what are you going to do if your header includes another header (eg: <time.h> if it uses time_t ) and that header defines some functions from standard libraries.

Comment: @Jasen I strictly not interested in some nested headers, only a strict comparison of functions in header and source.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Maybe that there is such a capability burried in the depths of emacs, but it's a pity that I haven't been able to find it yet :(

Answer (score 0):

I'd just do it with `grep` etc.:

```
grep ');' foo.h | tr -d ';' | while read decl
do
    if ! grep -q "$decl" foo.c
    then
        echo "not found: $decl"
    fi
done
```

No, this isn't perfect, but it might work if your use case is as simple as you've outlined.

Comment: In general it is that simple, but it seems that something with your approach is not really working. It lists every function mentioned in the header, despite its implementation in the sources.

Comment: in the header it will have `;` on the line with the prototype, in the `.c`  it will not.

Comment: Thats why the `tr` potion is there: remove the ";".

Comment: @NobbZ: I had a backslash in the first grep that I shouldn't have, now removed.  I tested with your example inputs and it works for me.  Make sure you remove the backslash as I did, and if it's still not working, time for a bit of debugging.  :)

Comment: I already removed it, because my `grep` didn't like it ;) I'll take a look into it later and try to nail that one down.